Which version of ag-grid (ag-grid-community/enterprise) supports 'maxNumConditions' filter parameter in case of agTextColumnFilter?
I am using ag-grid-community/ag-grid-enterprise version 26.1.0 in one of my react applications. But, maxNumConditions filter param (to control the number of conditions) is not working for both the types of filter agTextColumnFilter and agMultiColumnFilter.
My question is, which version shall I upgrade my libraries to, to get this parameter working?
I tried looking up the documentation but couldn't find exactly which version.
Thank you!

Got the answer from ag-grid's open source github code repo. Minimum version that supports maxNumConditions filter param is 29.2.0. Here is the Link to github codebase.
